# Howto speed up the Saxon doc() function?

Tags: xquery, saxon

I have a 12mb XML file which I am accessing from within an xquery. The file is loaded something like this;

```
let $t := doc('file:///C:/foo/bar/file12mb.xml')
```

The code is taking about 950ms to execute.

**How can the XML document be loaded faster?**
Once the xml file is loaded and parsed, the body of the xquery only takes a few milliseconds to run, so I'm trying to speed up the initial loading and parsing of the xml file which is taking the majority of the execution time.

**Is there any way for Saxon to persist an xml document after it has been parsed?**
Ideally I would like to persist the xml data file somehow but Saxon seems to be designed purely as an xml processor not an xml database.

**Would a Schema help?**
The xml file does not currently have a schema associated with it. The Saxon documentation implies that having a schema speeds up query execution but slows down the initial loading and parsing of the xml data, so I haven't tried creating a schema.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

**Versions**

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Saxon-B version 9.1.0.8
```

Comment: Probably you should consider using XML databases like Sedna, eXist? As you mentioned Saxon is processor, not a storage.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds pretty fast for parsing a 12MB file. I don't think you can optimize that, and no, Saxon is not a database.

In MarkLogic the parsing of the XML only ever happens once: during ingest. In other databases, such as Oracle, that may or may not be the case, depending on how you load it.